# Register flutter web plugins manually

Tags: flutter-web

Flutter is generating a file `generated_plugin_registrant.dart` for web project that looks like

```dart
void registerPlugins(PluginRegistry registry) {
  FirestoreWeb.registerWith(registry.registrarFor(FirestoreWeb));
  FirebaseAuthWeb.registerWith(registry.registrarFor(FirebaseAuthWeb));
  FirebaseCoreWeb.registerWith(registry.registrarFor(FirebaseCoreWeb));
  GoogleSignInPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor(GoogleSignInPlugin));
  SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor(SharedPreferencesPlugin));
  UrlLauncherPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor(UrlLauncherPlugin));
  registry.registerMessageHandler();
}
```

I would like to disable some plugins for the web only (FirestoreWeb is crashing because I don't have the proper web initialization and I don't want to). It is not possible to modify it but I would like to know if it is possible to have a custom `registerPlugins()` that could override the default behavior where I could manually register the plugin I want or disable in `pubspec.yaml` some plugin for the web only.

Comment: I know it's a couple of years ago but did you find a solution for this?